# ImageMagick - Convert PDF to JPG and Set Width

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am currently converting a PDF to a set of images using ImageMagick like this..

```
// create Imagick object
 $imagick = new Imagick();
 // Reads image from PDF
 $imagick->readImage('book.pdf');
 // Writes an image
 $imagick->writeImages('converted.jpg', false);
```

The resulting images are quite small, is there a way to set a defined width and then let the height work itself out?

Comment: Set the density (try 300dpi) after creating the image but before reading the PDF and then resize after loading the PDF. If you don't, ImageMagick will rasterise with a default density of 72 dpi making your images small and blocky.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers, will try them out now